Google forms downloading to Excel
You have obviously done an update a few weeks ago and its causing a lot of problems.
I use Google forms every day, I go to responses link to sheet, view in sheets, file, download Microsoft Excel.  Its always worked perfectly now it opens in a table rather than Excel sheet with loads of errors that then open in a word document and its a nightmare to work with
Please can you put it back to how it was.
Thanks
Anoushka
